# How can i get the text in span without using the span class

Tags: typescript, cheerio

i want to get the text in the span but without using the class gh__price

```
<div class="cell offer__price">
   <span class="gh__price">1200,00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.offer__price span').innerText
```